# R Create stacked bar chart from non-numerical data using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a stacked bar chart using non numerical data that would look like the ggplot one below

[image]

My data looks like this, read in as a CSV and contains 500+ obs. All rows for "Name" are unique.

```
Name      Group      Category
Philippe Cochet      NPA      Farmer  
Jacques Kossowski      NPA      Farmer 
Lionel Tardy      USD      Executive
Dominique Tian      USD      Executive
Dom Terril      ABC      Executive
```

I'd like the x axis to be the Category, and the y axis to be the count of Category. The bars would then be coloured by Group count. I imagine it might work something like this:

```
ggplot(z, aes("Category")) + geom_bar(aes(fill = "Group"))
```

I've also tried using a native barplot, but this won't stack the bars

```
z <- table(z$"Group",z$"Category")
barplot(z, beside = TRUE, legend = TRUE)
```

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for [geom_bar](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bar.html)? Notice the use of quotes (or the lack of them).

Comment: Yes I have but I'm a beginner. What part of the documentation?

Comment: Look at the examples at the bottom showing different ways to produce a bar plot. Note that in `ggplot`, when passing column names to `aes()`, you don't put quotes around them, just include them as unquoted symbols. So your `aes` calls should look like `aes(fill = Group)`.

Comment: Your only mistake is putting quotation marks around column names. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fill = Group` needs to be inside the `aes` *without quotation marks*.  Try:

```
ggplot(z, aes(Category, fill = Group)) + geom_bar()
```

or, in keeping with the `geom_bar` help page:

```
ggplot(z, aes(Category)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = Group))
```

These will both give the desired result:
[image]